# Edit Unicode character mapping of PDF manually char by char

Tags: vb.net, pdf, unicode, fonts, remap

I have a PDF file its Unicode is broken, it is readable in PDF Reader but when I copy some text and paste it in text editor, it shows as symbols and gibberish or wierd characters, I don't want to know why this happened just I want to create a program (or get one is better but free) to change Unicode characters manually char by char against its glyph and apply to entier PDF document.

[Edit Unicode mapping of PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09MhF.png)

Comment: Which text editor, and does the font it is using include glyphs for the characters you are pasting in to it?

Comment: Notepad++, Windows Notepad, MS Word and others. no when I copy some text in PDF Reader it just copy plain text not their fonts with it, i don't want the fonts cause the Unicode of fonts in PDF is broken, also I used PDF Convertor the result is the same

Comment: Perhaps the [mutool clean](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-clean.html) command from mupdf would help - you could get the uncompressed PDF data, which could be easier to work with (if the cleaned PDF doesn't work as is).

Comment: I used mutool clean and mutool extract, again the same result, but I can extract fonts with this tool, maybe I do something with it. Thank you Andrew for your help

Comment: Try with ms word, highlight the uncorrect char, get the ascii code for the selected char with macro, and with macro too, you replace all the char of the selected ascii code to the correct char.